# Would you recommend Java/Glassfish/Metro for brand-new project?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, glassfish, legacy

I developed in ASP.NET 2.0 for some time, and for slightly less time in Java/Spring/Hibernate. Right now I start developing new web-service and am confused with the choice of:

.NET WCF 3.5 versus Java/Metro.

From one side, WCF seems like a brilliantly developed solution, a masterpiece of software frameworks, with all the support for functional languages, easy wizards, simple architecture. The downside is that it seems to be running on Windows only (Mono doesn't support WCF) and doesn't integrate so beautifully with Ruby on Rails (through JRuby as Java does).

And Java seems really outdated -- no operator overloading or generic arrays?!

So, my main question is: **would anyone here start a new project using Java or is it just a dying language for legacy software?**

PS. *Both* performance *and* database connectivity are major priorities so that leaves slow Perl, Ruby, or Python and database-unfriendly C++ out of the question.

PPS. For presentation layer I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a Rails application, JRuby on Glassfish is a winning combination. I have five Rails apps deployed to Glassfish and I haven't had any problems so far. I have been impressed with the performance and deployment was super easy.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of activity in the Java world. I talk to many customers deploying new projects in Java. I also see lots of activity in JRuby and other dynamic languages. Take a look at the Tiobe Index for a more :
http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

As for Metro, on GlassFish, you can call Java libraries from dynamic languages (and vice-versa), so Project Metro with Java, JRuby, etc, is an option.

John Clingan,
GlassFish Group Product Manager

Answer (score 0):

your observation is quite biased i think. the main thing is need. do you require generic arrays for everything or you can do all the thing efficiently without the help of generic arrays ... :) and Java is not outdated .. it is actually a GIANT . a v. big GIANT . it depends on your project how you are going to do it manage it and what services you are going to run as you yourself said abt the ROR . give a shot on Java you will surely live in it  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that both suggestions fit your needs equally good. So when you are more familiar with the .NET tools and libraries you should stick to that since there is not much value in learning two things that do (about) the same. Specially when those things are as complex.